# Sending mail with attachment in linux terminal

Tags: linux, email, terminal, console, gmail

I'm trying to send an email with attachment to my google account, because i need to share file.c with my code from classes at the university.

We have accounts on university server on linux and We can use it at home, but only in terminal.

I tried to use this comand:

> mail -s "Topic" myaccount@gmail.com < file.c

but it is not delivered to my gmail account. The only message is:

> You have new mail in /var/mail/myaccount

Do you know what's the reason that it can't be delivered to my gmail account? Or another command to send email?

Comment: Check the logs in /var/log/maillog

Comment: Could you explain little more? I'm beginner so i don't know much. Why it could help?

Comment: I already checked it and I have permission denied

Comment: You need to read it as a root user. `sudo nano /var/log/maillog`. This will help you determine why your email isn't sending.

Comment: I did it too and i got a message: 
_5witkos is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported._
I am only a user on the server ;/ any other ideas?

Comment: You need to reset your admin password. See http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/179959

Comment: i am not admin on that server i am conecting with this by Putty ssh protocol.

I only got a user account on university server.